# Inline CSS looks different when looping through

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript

I have a solution which have boxes. If the user wants three boxes it will look like this:
[image]

The user can also choose 2 different colors for _each_box. If the user choose one color for one box, the box background color will be changed to that color. If the user enter two colors instead, a linear gradient will be set. These data will be sent as a variable via props:

firstColorBox1
secondColorBox1
firstColorBox2
secondColorBox2

and so on. These can have values such as "red" or hex-codes. I also have another props "nrofboxes" which is the number of boxes. I use this variable for my for loops.

To dynamically change the css of the boxes, I am using inline CSS which is manipulated via props. In short, I have a state with an empty array. Each box inline style properties will be saved in this array and extracted via its index in a for-loop. Too handle each box specific css style I have done like this:

I have an empy array in state where each individual style object till be added to:

```
boxStyle: []
```

in componentDidMount

```
for (var i = 1; i <= Number(this.props.nrofboxes); i++){
let style = {backgroundColor:"",  };
let concatToState;

if(this.props["firstColorBox" + i] || this.props["secondColorBox" + i] ) {
  if(this.props["firstColorBox" + i] && this.props["secondColorBox" + i] ){
    style["backgroundImage"] = `linear-gradient(${this.props["firstColorBox" + i]}, ${this.props["secondColorBox" + i]})`
    concatToState = this.state.boxStyle.concat(style);
    this.setState({boxStyle:concatToState})
  }

  else if(this.props["firstColorBox" + i]) {
    style.backgroundColor = `${this.props["firstColorBox" + i]}`
    concatToState = this.state.boxStyle.concat(style);
    this.setState({boxStyle:concatToState})
  } }}
```

Above I have a loop for each box, and I check if it has value in both props and if so --> add linear gradient, and if not --> add background color. Notice how I go through each box dynamically via:

```
this.props["firstColorBox" + i]
```

I then add the value of the color/props to an object, and concat it to state:

```
 style.backgroundColor = `${this.props["firstColorBox" + i]}`
        concatToState = this.state.boxStyle.concat(style);
        this.setState({boxStyle:concatToState})
```

The idea is to take the index of the specific box style in the state array in a for loop in render.

In render, I output all boxes via a for loop:

```
   for (var i = 1; i <= Number(nrofboxes); i++){
      boxes.push(
        <div className={globalStyles["a-Grid-col"] + " " + globalStyles["w-sm12"] + " " + globalStyles["w-lg" + size]  + " " + globalStyles["w-xl" + size] + " " + styles["w-link-box-container"]}>
          <div className={styles["link-box"]} >
            <a href={this.props["linkurl" + i]} style={this.state.boxStyle[i]} >
              <h4 className={styles["link-box-header-container"]}>
                <small className={styles["link-box-header-title"] + " " + (this.props.themefontcolor ? styles["w-themed-color"] : "")}>{this.props["linktitle" + i]}</small>
                <span className={styles["link-box-header-text"] + " " + (this.props.themefontcolor ? styles["w-themed-color"] : "")}>{this.props["linktext" + i]}</span>
              </h4>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

As you can see above, I try to get each specific style object from the state via the for loop like this:

```
style={this.state.boxStyle[i]}
```

However, it does not work. If the firstColorBox1 is = "red", the expected behaviour would be that only the first box will be red but it looks like this:

[image]

2 problems: instead of a red background color, the border is red. And not only that, all three boxes are affected by it instead of only the first one.

And if I hardcode the inline style to be red like this:

```
 style={{backgroundColor:"red"}}
```

it will look like this:
[image]

It should be equal, but there is no red border and the backgroundColor is set properly. Why is that? I guess something with my loops is wrong.

Comment: You're having `style ={this.state.boxStyle[0]}` in your loop, so always looking for the first element, not `i`

Comment: I did some tests and forgot to delete that part,  I have edited it now. So the problem exists even with boxStyle[i]

Comment: Why are you doing anything in `componentDidMount`? It feels like you'd be better doing that all in render?

Comment: It will cause to many re-renders if I do it anywhere but in componentDidMount.